# .netrc is not used when venv is active

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-venv, .netrc

I have set up a private pypi package index in gitlab.

In my `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` I setup an extra-index-url

```
# pip.conf
[global]
extra-index-url=https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/60/-/packages/pypi/simple
```

Next I setup a `~/.netrc`

```
# .netrc
machine gitlab.example.com
login my_username
```

The password has been saved in `keyring`

When I install a package in my system python like

```
$ pip install my-package
```

everything works as expected (no interaction, neither asking for user, nor for a password).

But if I activate a virtual environment

```
(venv)$ pip install my-package
```

I get asked for user and password of the gitlab instance.

Does someone know, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
(.venv) <user>@laptop:~/test$ pip config list -v
For variant 'global', will try loading '/home/<user>/.config/kdedefaults/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/home/<user>/.pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/home/<user>/.config/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'site', will try loading '/home/<user>/test/.venv/pip.conf'
global.extra-index-url='https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/60/-/packages/pypi/simple'
```

and without venv

```
<user>@laptop:~/test$ pip config list -v
For variant 'global', will try loading '/home/<user>/.config/kdedefaults/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'global', will try loading '/etc/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/home/<user>/.pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'user', will try loading '/home/<user>/.config/pip/pip.conf'
For variant 'site', will try loading '/usr/pip.conf'
global.extra-index-url='https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/60/-/packages/pypi/simple'
```

Comment: Can you run this `pip config list -v` to see the difference between the two environments ?

Comment: @Philippe I added the output of `pip config list -v`

Comment: Does it work when the NETRC env var is set with `NETRC=/home/<user>/.netrc pip install my-package` ?

Comment: Can you see if `/home/<user>/test/.venv/pip.conf` gives any clue ?

Comment: There is no `pip.conf` in my venv.

Comment: @BoppreH Nope, this does not change anything.

Comment: When I create a `venv` with `--system-site-packages` option, credentials are used. I assume, that some packages are missing.